# String Concatenation not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, ternary-operator, string-concatenation

I am trying this code

```
<script>
    var x=1;
    var temp = '{"value":'+ (x==1)?1:0 +'}';
    console.log(temp);
</script>
```

and expecting to give output like this
**`{"value":1}`**
but it is consoling only **`1`** 
why not the whole obj. string
can anyone tell me that what's wrong ?

Comment: `(parentheses)`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol will you please tell me in a little bit more detail

Comment: `x==1?1:0` -> `(x==1?1:0)` perhaps

Comment: I want to get output like this {"value":1}

Comment: While you can overcome operator precedence with parentheses as shown in the comments above, in modern implementations, you no longer need concatenation because template literals are available. `var temp = \`{"value":${(x==1)?1:0}}\`;`

Answer (score 1):

Beside the missing parenthesis

```
var temp = '{"value":'+ (x == 1 ? 1 : 0) +'}';
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to give the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) a higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) over the plus sign, you could use a different approach by using a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for an object with ES6.

Thi sgenerates an object, instead of a string, which is better to generate. For using a stringified value, [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) creates a string in the wanted format.

```js
var x = 1,
    value = x === 1 ? 1 : 0,
    temp = { value };

console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary statement is immediately followed by another `+` which it doesn't understand how to read. It appears incomplete as "0 + " [...nothing].

To evaluate that statement separately for use in the concatenated string, you need to either evaluate it in another statement, or enclose it in parentheses.

```js
var x=1;
var temp = '{"value":'+ (x == 1 ? 1:0) +'}';
console.log(temp)
```

Or, you could use [ES6 Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) string interpolation instead of using `+` signs to concatenate the separate parts ... This syntax evaluates your ternary expression inline, then places the result inside the variable placeholder indicated by the dollar sign & curly braces `${[variable]}`. The resulting string prints the value of the interpreted expression.

```
var temp = `{"value":${(x == 1) ? 1:0}}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your expression like below

var temp = '{"value":'+ (x==1?1:0) +'}';